# Call method to get variable from Scanner and assign it to a new variable

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am struggling with method calling especially when using it with Scanner.

I'm given this little piece of code;

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Calendar;    // for date calcs

public class UtilsMS {

// user input methods, by datatype ----------------------------------------

// get an int value
public static int readInt(String prompt) 
{
    // set up data and objects
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int data;

    // prompt for an input int value
    System.out.print(prompt);
    data = input.nextInt();       

    return data;
}
```

And so I go into my main client Java code and try;

```
public class AgeClientMS
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {   
        // Declarations
        int todayDate, todayCal;
        String getMonth = "Enter birth month: ";
        String getDay = "Enter birth day: ";
        String getYear = "Enter birth year: ";
        int data;

        // Methods

        UtilsMS.readInt(getMonth);
        UtilsMS.readInt(getDay);
        UtilsMS.readInt(getYear);

        //Outputs, Formatting, Display
    }
}
```

This is as far as I can figure out what to do, I realize I need to grab an INT value using the scanner in my UtilsMS class and then re-assign it another value so I can use each value I grab into a future SimpleDate date.
I just cannot figure out how to re-assign the value.

Comment: `int month = UtilsMS.readInt(getMonth);`...?

Comment: What are you trying to do, you did not tell us ?

Comment: you initialize and assign ints just like you did with the strings (although that is a shortcut syntax) `int <var_name> = <some_expression_that_evaluates_to_an_int>`  In your case, @MadProgrammer has it

Comment: You don't need to create new Scanner object on every method call.

Comment: the [return] statement will not perofrm as System.out.println(input.nexInt()); . return statement will just keep the data and stored for other methods to ask for it. or variables. etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you are trying to do. And based on the fact that you have a field for today's date, I'm guessing you are trying to compute the age of the person as well. So I basically answered your question in this code, and also did a few other things with it too that I think you are trying to do.

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class AgeClientMS
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {   
        // Declarations
        int todayDate, todayCal;
        String getMonth = "Enter birth month: ";
        String getDay = "Enter birth day: ";
        String getYear = "Enter birth year: ";
        int data;

        // Methods

        // UtilsMS returns an integer value which we store in variables.
        int birthMonth = UtilsMS.readInt(getMonth);
        int birthDay = UtilsMS.readInt(getDay);
        int birthYear = UtilsMS.readInt(getYear);

        //Outputs, Formatting, Display 

        Calendar birthCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        birthCalendar.set(birthYear, birthMonth - 1, birthDay);

        Calendar todayCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        long ageInMilliseconds = todayCalendar.getTimeInMillis() - birthCalendar.getTimeInMillis();
        System.out.println("Age In Milliseconds: " + ageInMilliseconds);
        System.out.println("Age In Years: " + ((ageInMilliseconds / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / 365));


        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
        try {
            Date birthDate = format.parse(birthMonth + "/" + birthDay + "/" + birthYear);
            System.out.println("You were born on: " + birthDate);


        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```